# React- How to pass props between two different Microfrontent component

Tags: reactjs

I am using microfrontend, In that I have a main container which uses these two Microfrontend component, and these three component are in different repo.

I have one React component in one repo:

```
class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.props.component}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have a different component In another repo(other Microfrontend component) that use it:

```
class SomeContainer extends React.Component {
   render() {
    let someObjectVariable = {someProperty: 'someValue'};
    return (
      <CustomForm 
         component={<SomeInnerComponent someProp={'someInnerComponentOwnProp'}/>}
         object={someObjectVariable}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to pass props between two different Microfrontend component?

Answer (score 0):

Your proptype for `component` in `CustomForm` will need to accept ReactNodes.

But you should be able to pass it through as a function (Meaning without the `<` and `/>`:

if you do not need to pass any custom props, you can just call
`<CustomForm component={SomeInnerComponent} .... />`

If you need the custom props, you can wrap it in another function and just pass that through:

```
<CustomForm component={ () => { 
   return <SomeInnerComponent someProp={'someInnerComponentOwnProp'}/>;
}} ...... />
```

The reasoning behind this is that because Functional components in React are actually just Functions, you can pass through a component as a prop without the `<` or `/>` and then it will just execute that as a function.

Comment: This is not working in case of microfrontend structure.

Comment: @deepakprem I think then maybe you need to clarify your question a bit. It is not clear to me exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: sure @mark, Acutally in my React project I have one main component( skeleton part which contain header,menubar etc ) and it is in one repository of git, and its different components are coming from different repos of git, they are basically using microfrontend structure like we have microservices in the backend. so, for that I want to know how to pass props between these microfrontent components.

Comment: @deepakprem Sorry for only getting back to you now. I understand the structure and layout of the project, but I don't quite understand with what you mean by passing props between the microfrontend components. Could you expand on your example to give a clearer explanation?